# How to stop SAPUI5 Button from submitting the form

Tags: javascript, button, sapui5, event-listener

I have a simple mytable.view.xml with a table and a button. This table is just one among others in a form and all the tables are handled through different view.xml.

```
<mvc:view>
     <l:VerticalLayout>
           //Code for table headers and table
     </l:VerticalLayout>
     <Button id="myButton" text="test" visible="true"  press="onMyButtonClicked"/>
</mvc:view>
```

Controller:

```
onMyButtonClicked: function(){
     window.location.href = "http://example.com/;
}
```

onMyButtonClicked is getting invoked when I click on button, but that is being overridden by form submit. Since there is no logic to handle this submit, the page is just reloading instead of navigating to http://example.com/. In developer tools of browser I noticed that the navigate to example.com is being triggered and is cancelled.
One thing I tried and worked was inspecting this button on browser and adding a `onclick="return false;"` in the button tag. But from sap.m.button I cannot do this.
Tried event.PreventDefault(). This didn't work either.

Is there any other way to stop this button from behaving like a submit button?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce that behavior. Could you please add an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to the question? You can fork this [basic UI5 plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/16J1TFICxbqETCzaxuZ0) and share the URL.

Answer (score 0):

A button won't trigger anything if the press event is not bound. For your case why not just remove the press event binding to a callback? Am I missing something? UI5 buttons don't behave like HTML button of type "submit" inside a form.